# How to write AngularJS directive that generates another directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I use the [alert directive](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/alert) like this:

```
<alert ng-repeat="alert in alerts" type="'danger'">{{alert}}</alert>
```

where `alerts` is something like: `['Hello', 'World']`.

I would like to create an `alerts` directive which will be used like this:

```
<alerts model="alerts"></alerts>
```

which will be equivalent to the above.

I tried to start with: ([live demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/ENrEjZBNS5akSzx7BlDt?p=preview))

```
app.directive('alerts', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      model: '='
    },
    template: '<alert ng-repeat="alert in {{model}}" type="\'danger\'"></alert>'
  };
});
```

but I get the following error:

```
Syntax Error: Token 'model' is unexpected, expecting [:] at column 3 of the expression [{{model}}] starting at [model}}].
```

Why is that?

What would be the right way to implement the `alerts` directive?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove {{ and }} from the `ng-repeat` binding in the template. It would work. You do not need to use {{ }} inside an expression.